# Rails i18n.default_locale and date format ... doesn't seem to be acting like a default

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, date, internationalization

I want Rails (3.2) to use the American date format 03/14/2012 unless I say otherwise.

I have the I18n gem installed, downloaded (and modified) the `config/locales/en-US.yml` file to have the default format as `default: ! '%m/%d/%Y'`, set my `application.rb` default locale as `config.i18n.default_locale = "en-US"`, and restarted.

When dates are displayed (e.g. a simple view) they still have the format 2012-03-14.  If I use the `I18n.l` method, the date displays as desired, 03/14/2012.  So localization is working through the I18n class.

I guess I was expecting the meaning of "default" to be, "this is the one to use if you're not otherwise told to localize or translate."  Apparently I expected wrong :-)

So further digging revealed I could change the defaults for date and time in an initializer, such as `config/initializers/date_formats.rb`, e.g.

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%m/%d/%Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
```

This appears to do what I want.  Several alarming posts suggests that this will screw up how dates are stored in the database, but my tests (using PostgreSQL) suggest that this is not a problem.

So (rant) why the heck shouldn't all apps observe the default locale without wrapping every date on the face of the earth with `l` and `t` helpers?

And (actual question) will I cause permanent harm to myself or others by changing the default date and time formats for my application in an initializer?

Comment: I am having the same issue. A couple of comments on what you have done though:

Comment: I am having the same issue. I don't think that i18n gem is required when using rails 3.2, I believe it is baked in. My en.yml looks like this: en:
  date:
    formats:
      # Use the strftime parameters for formats.
      # When no format has been given, it uses default.
      # You can provide other formats here if you like!
      default:  "%m/%d/%Y"
      american:  "%m/%d/%Y"

Comment: hm yeah - it looks like it just doesn't apply the default localization unless you tell it to localize...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and this gem helped me https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date

Just add it to your Gemfile, no settings needed